# login page without header/breadcrumb/footer

Tags: angular, angular6, primeng

I using `PrimeNG` theme with `Angular`. I want create login component, which contains login form. I create component:

```
ng generate component login
```

and add to `app.routes.ts`:

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {CampaignsOverviewComponent} from "./campaigns/campaigns-overview/campaigns-overview.component";
import {LoginComponent} from "./login/login.component";

export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/campaigns', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'campaigns', component: CampaignsOverviewComponent},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
];

export const AppRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    useHash: true
});
```

When I follow to the 'login' page, I see:

[image]

As you can see, my component is embedded inside. But, I need to display my page on top of everything, so that the page has only the authorization form, without titles, menus and other things. How can this be done?

Comment: I think you have the header and footer code in the app.component.html file. If it is present then remove it and keep only  '<router-outlet>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have separate Shell Component `AppLayoutComponent` which has layout stuff like header, footer, menu etc and all Component should be Injected into this Shell Component except Login Component.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{ 
path: '',
   component: AppLayoutComponent, 
   children: [
          { path: 'campaigns', component: CampaignsOverviewComponent },
          { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
        ]
    },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent} ]
```

> app-layout.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

> app-layout.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-layout',
  templateUrl: './app-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-layout.component.css']
})
export class AppLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

For reference see example of layout here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example-qhpupz

Comment: I do not quite understand what should be in the markup of my login component and how to connect it

Comment: You just need to change in the routing and introduce new component `AppLayoutComponent`. Login component will be as it is. For reference I had given the link.

Comment: I try run your project, but I have error: compiler_1.Version is not a constructor
TypeError: compiler_1.Version is not a constructor

Comment: can you replicate your issue in stackblitz ? It will be easier to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this easily just playing with CSS.

Suppose this is the HTML code in your 
**login.component.html**. I am using **loginLayout** class at main div

```
<div class="loginLayout">
  <div class="textOnPage">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userDetail.username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pwd">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userDetail.password">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simply what you need to do is, in you **login.component.scss** Use below CSS properties
for loginLayout class.

```
.loginLayout{
    background: #000;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%; 
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:200;
}
```